# Postgresql csv importation that skips rows

Tags: postgresql, csv-import

I have a Postgresql script that automatically imports csv files into my database. The script can detect duplicate records and remove them, do a proper upsert but still cannot tackle everything. Basically the csv files are exported from other systems which append at the beginning and end of the file extra information e.g:

```
Total Count: 2956
Avg Time: 13ms

Column1, Column2, Column3
...      ...      ...
```

What I want to do is skip those initial rows or any rows at the bottom of the file. Is there any way I can do this in Postgresql via COPY or via another route whatever that might be? Can I call for instance operating system commands via Postgresql?

Answer (score 3):

For Linux use `tail` and `head` to crop the file and pipe it to your script:

```
tail -n +3 file.csv | head -1 | psql -f my_script.sql my_database
```

Then your script will copy from STDIN:

```
copy my_table from STDIN;
```

Comment: sorry I dont have much experience with Postgresql. Are the tail and head commands invoked via the Postgresql console? How can I set this up?

Comment: @Dimitris. Via the Linux command line. I guess Windows will have its counter parts.

Comment: Unfortunately this is on a Windows machine. That's what the client has. So I guess I will need to look for the equivalent in Windows