# How to bulk Insert in Postgres ignoring all errors that may occur in the process?

Tags: postgresql

I have to insert a good amount of log records every hour in a table and I would not care about Integrity Errors or Violations that happen in the process.

If I disable autoCommit and do a bulk insert, cursor wont insert anything beyond the row where the transaction failed. Is there a way around this one ?

One hack is to handle this at the application level.
I could implement a n-sized buffer and do bulk inserts. If something failed in that transaction, recursively repeat the insert for buffer_first_half + buffer_second_half

```
def insert(buffer):
    try:
        bulk_insert(buffer)
    except:
        connection.rollback()

        marker = len(buffer)/2

        insert(buffer[:marker])
        insert(buffer[marker:])
```

But I really hope if it could be achieved using any Postgres' built-in ?

Comment: Did you search this site before asking this? It's a real FAQ.

Comment: Actually I did. If you may like I can share the links of the questions I deem were similar. Mostly, someone would end up answering it with a "do not make an update on this column." "Change your fkey".. <place any other reason>. I am plainly looking for a generic answer. Which btw you have provided. Thank you :-)

Comment: No worries. It's worth mentioning what you tried / looked into first, that's all. Sometimes it'll save you from getting the same things suggested to you all over again.

Comment: Well, if it fits in a (python?) buffer, it cannot be bulk. BTW: you don't need to rollback on error. An error implies a rollback.

Comment: That code was more convenience sake :-) I was anyway going to send batches of values. Say, 10K rows at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't provide anything built-in for this. You can use `SAVEPOINT`s, but they're not much better than individual transactions.

Treat each insert as an individual transaction and work on making those tx's faster:

- `SET synchronous_commit = off` in your session
- `INSERT` into an `UNLOGGED` table, then `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` the results into the real table after checking

[Here's an earlier closely related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20170164/398670) which also links to more information. I haven't marked this as a duplicate because the other one is specific to upsert-like data loading, you're interested in more general error handling.

Comment: I think I am still left with a doubt.Say I dump the data into a collection without any checks/conditions, the final routine which weeds out corrupt data and inserts into production table would be triggered by the application or a Cron ? If so, How would it be different from weeding out unwanted data at Stage 1 itself and inserting directly into production table ?

Comment: @meson10 Because you can do the weeding in a big set operation, you don't have to do it one by one in individual transactions. Operations on sets are generally significantly faster.